# Multiple functions in single azure app not triggering

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have 2 different functions in single azure app and both the functions are triggers using azure storage on 2 different containers or file system. The issue I am facing is, only one function is triggers at a time. If both the functions are enabled, only the first one is triggered and other one is not triggered. If I enable one function only that function is triggered which is as expected. What could be the possible issue?

Is there any issue in Azure functions.

Comment: How did you test to come to a conclusion：`only one function is triggers at a time`? So did you mean all the time no  matter how many functions you have you could only trigger one blob function, others could not be triggered(with different path)? In my test two blob function with different path could be triggered, however I trigger them one by one(could not upload the blobs at a time).

Comment: Any update on this issue? Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes.. the trigger was very late. Took hours to trigger. Could be a one off case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize an answer to close this issue:

This should not be an issue and it can work well at our side(no delay). As you mentioned, finally the trigger fires but very late, this may due to some internal issue and if the issue still exists, please [raise a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to azure support team.

Comment: Support ticket is already raised. We are trying to repro it again